# What is the actual application when APP_NAME() = Microsoft® Windows® Operating System in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

There is trigger on a table which gets application name using the SQL function APP_NAME() and inserts it in a table. The APP_NAME() in the table is 'Microsoft® Windows® Operating System'. So what is it? Is it a windows service or any other?

Comment: You do know that the application name is provided by the client right? That means it could be absolutely anything that established a connection passing that value as the application name.

Comment: If the process is still running, just check what it is using the process id.